# Rails routes - getting a directory listing instead of the "Hello, Rails!" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm going through the Rails [getting started tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and I'm having trouble with the routing part. I'm at the part right after they have you delete `public/index.html` and change `config/routes.rb`. When I visit my project in the browser, I get a directory listing instead of the "Hello, Rails!" thing. If I bring back `public/index.html`, I see the "Welcome aboard" page again.

Here's my `config/routes.rb` minus comments:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

I've tried removing the `get "home/index"` line and that doesn't fix it.

Comment: hmm, that's weird. I assume that you're running the server on your local computer, right and that you've started it up by running `rails server`? I'm sorry if that's a stupid question. I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. I'm actually running Apache and I'm looking at my page from a remote machine. I did not run `rails server`.

Comment: When I ran `rails server` and went to `http://myurl:3000`, I got this: "Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter)", then when I tried to install that, it said no such gem exists.

Comment: Okay, I'm past that and now I get `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`.

Comment: Are you using a Postgres database?

Comment: Yes, and I started a separate question for the fact that I can't connect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565494/cant-log-into-postgresql-database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to tell Rails what to route `home/index` *to*.

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index" => "home#index"
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Comment: You actually don't have to do that. `get "home/index"` will map the route /home/index. Look at an example in the Rails Guides here under HTTP Verb Constraints: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

Comment: In any case, it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rails itself would never return a directory listing. Whatever you are using to run your Rails application is not configured correctly. More than likely you have configured it to point to the root of the Rails application rather than the public folder inside of it.

Hard to tell, given the lack of information in the question.