# Can't log into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I created a user like this:

```
create user blog with password 'blog';
```

Then I made it the owner of a database:

```
alter database blog_development owner to blog;
```

Then I tried to log in and it didn't work:

```
$ psql -d blog_development -U blog -W
Password for user blog:
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "blog"
```

Any idea why?

One thing I've tried is editing `pg_hba.conf`

```
 76 # Database administrative login by UNIX sockets
 77 local   all                postgres                          ident
 78
 79 # TYPE  DATABASE           USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
 80
 81 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
 82 local   all                all                               ident
 83 # IPv4 local connections:
 84 host    all                all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
 85 host    blog_development   blog        127.0.0.1/32          md5
 86 # IPv6 local connections:
 87 host    all                all         ::1/128               md5
```

Line 85 is the one I added. I restarted PostgreSQL after that but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Interestingly, I can log in remotely via pgAdmin III (after adding another line to `pg_hba.conf`) but I still can't log in from the command line.

Comment: Also, I can connect via a PHP script. I'm starting to think I'm trying to log in the wrong way.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was just trying to connect in the wrong way. Here's the right way:

```
psql -h localhost -U blog -d blog_development
```

Comment: yeah, without a -h host pgsql tries to log in on local unix sockets i.e. the line that starts with local and ends with ident is what's getting in the way.

Answer (score 5):

psql uses a local socket by default (check out -h flag in man) - that should match line 82 when you log in.

> 82 local   all                all                               ident

`ident` needs a real user in the system to check the password against. So you can either connect by host or add an user so it matches you new config line.

Comment: Or change the local all all ident to something else as well.

Answer (score 4):

Before line 82, add

```
local   blog_development   blog   md5
```

and reload, or connect using `-h localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the user to pg_hba.conf? Here is the documentation.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

I don't really remember the exact syntax but you should add something like this:

```
host    blog_development     blog  127.0.0.1/32  md5
```

You might need to reload or restart the server so that pg_hba.conf is reread.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that but it didn't seem to work. See my edit to see what I changed.