# Rails app won't connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm coming from the PHP/MySQL world, trying to set up a Rails/PostgreSQL app. It doesn't seem to want to connect and I'm having a hard time pinning down the cause of the problem. Are there certain troubleshooting steps I can take to figure out what's going wrong?

Update: the problem is not with PostgreSQL. I can connect to PostgreSQL via the command line, remotely via an IDE, and via a PHP script. I just can't seem to connect to it through this Rails app.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565494/cant-log-into-postgresql-database

Comment: which platform are you on? on linux et al, you can use strace to trace the system calls a command line program is doing (e.g. rails console), and using "strace -e trace=network,open" will typically show up which config files it's reading and which address/ports it is trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd start with the actual database.yml file to make sure i have all the right user and password information.

I'd also make sure i ran whatever it is you do to make postgres start it's server, so that connections can be established.  (Whether you use a `psql start` or it starts when you start your dev env.  So only you can answer that one).

Is the database created?

Can i connect through console? `rails console` shouldn't give an error.

Do you have the correct postgres gem installed and is that in your bundle file (or environment.rb file)?

Comment: well don't leave me hanging, what did you do!?!?